# How to check if multiple conditions are met

Tags: arduino-uno

I want to see if a number goes over a certain value(15) and light up a LED but whenever i run this code it gives me no errors but it doesn't do anything either...i hope someone can help, thanks in advance.

```
byte a0 = 1;
byte a1 = 1;
byte a2 = 1;
byte a3 = 1;

byte b0 = 1;
byte b1 = 1;
byte b2 = 1;
byte b3 = 1;

int Ov_soma(byte n1,byte n2,byte n3,byte n4,byte n5, byte n6,byte n7,byte n8){
  int volatile v1 = 0;
  int volatile v2 = 0;
  int volatile v3 = 0;
  int volatile v4 = 0;
  int volatile v5 = 0;
  int volatile v6 = 0;
  int volatile v7 = 0;
  int volatile v8 = 0;
  if(n1 == 1){
    return v1 = 1;
  }
  else{
    return v1;
  }

  if(n2 == 1){
    return v2 = 2;
  }
  else{
    return v2;
  }

  if(n3 == 1){
    return v3 = 4;
  }
  else{
    return v3;
  }

  if(n4 == 1){
    return v4 = 8;
  }
  else{
    return v4;
  }
  if(n5 == 1){
    return v5 = 1;
  }
  else{
    return v5;
  }

  if(n6 == 1){
    return v6 = 2;
  }
  else{
    return v6;
  }

  if(n7 == 1){
    return v7 = 4;
  }
  else{
    return v7;
  }

  if(n8 == 1){
    return v8 = 8;
  }
  else{
   return v8;
  }
  if((v1+v2+v3+v4+v5+v6+v7+v8) > 15){
    digitalWrite(9, HIGH);
  }
  else{
    digitalWrite(9, LOW);
  }
  Serial.println(v1+v2+v3+v4+v5+v6+v7+v8);
}


void setup() {
  Ov_soma(a0,a1,a2,a3,b0,b1,b2,b3);
}
```

So what i get is absolutely nothing and what i need is for the LED to light up if (v1+v2+v3+v4+v5+v6+v7+v8) > 15.

Comment: You ask a silly question read the whole solution again and try using switch when you  have multiple cases instead of if. HINT: return statements are too many.

Comment: I just realized what i did, that really was stupid, thank you!